# Lowering build size

Tags: c++, runtime

Is there any way I can lower my build size when I am using static linking for the C++ runtime libraries in VS2013?

My original file was just 15kb, but I couldn't run it on my other computers without a missing .dll message popping up. I decided to use static linking and now the size is ~100kb.

I am using the `Windows.h` header and WinAPI functions.

Comment: is that missing dll from windows or your own?

Comment: It can probably be made smaller, but it's hard to guess at details without seeing source code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It is a simple Message Box that says "Hello World".

Comment: @Digital_Reality It is a missing dll from Windows.

Comment: You can install the DLL runtime on another computer using the appropriate package from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784  Also, 100KB isn't really all that big.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh, okay. 
It seemed like a big jump from 15kb. For a simple message box.

Comment: Also, you might be able to use techniques from this old, old (1996) MSDN Magazine article: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/s572.aspx, but I suspect that probably a lot of the information there is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to display a MessageBox, you don't need to link to *any* static libraries.

```
#include <windows.h>

void entry(void) {    
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello, World!", "", MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Compile and link using VC++2013, with the following command line:

> cl  /O1 /GS- hello32.c /link /nodefaultlib /entry:entry /subsystem:windows user32.lib kernel32.lib

At least for me (with VC++ 2013) that produces an executable of 2560 bytes (that depends only on core Windows DLLs, so it shouldn't require anything extra to run on even the most bare-bones system).

Answer (score 1):

As your main intention is to keep size in control, `dll` is way to go.

As far as your missing dll is concerned it can be addressed.
If you are using standard libary missing error then its good idea to install redistributable on machine where you are running application.

[Redistributable for VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: I want to save the people the hassle from having to download this when they run my programs. Does static linking only link the necessary libraries or everything?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use MFC etc. you can

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
```

to reduce size of your code

Comment: I don't think that reduces code size - it's an old, now largely meaningless,  way of cutting down on compile time: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/30/9929944.aspx