# New application in c++ without any dependency

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a simple c++ hello word application that doesn't need any dependency.
I try to compile using visual studio c++ with /MT option but the release debug exe is about 1 MB (I think the file size for such simple app is way too big). Is this because of visual studio , do i need another compiler or i'm doing something wrong with visual studio ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might this be a dupe? E.g., of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20943392/179910

Comment: You might look into chucking the runtime, and going directly to the WIN32 APIs.

Comment: Enable optimizations, and try again Also, how is 1MB "too big"? Are you targeting a 720KB floppy disk?

Comment: Welcome to the world of modern compilers - EVERYTHING turns into a megabyte... ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not, you cannot trim it down to several 100k using a decent toolchain for an embedded target though ;) ...

Comment: Use /MD instead of /MT

Comment: I just create a simple windows console application with a printf of hello world and it came in at 40kb in debug and the release build is 5.50KB so not sure what you are doing to make such a large executable.

Comment: Richard, what compiler do you use ?